# Equivalent of C++'s std::atomic in Python

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, atomic

Is there an equivalent of `std::atomic` in Python or the only way of having this behavior if by using  a lock from `threading.Lock()`?

Because as I see it, the `Look` is exactly like `std::mutex`, so is there anything more similar to `std::atomic`?

Comment: Given that python's integers are arbitrary precision, atomics may not work so well.

Comment: The global interpreter lock (GIL) prevents multiple threads from running simultaneously, so there is no need for atomics to synchronize state.

Comment: @Botje Thank you! I'll look more deeply into this GIL thing